# Table header not rendering properly in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have ajax call which returns some array of objects after I edit some values and click submit (this form is in modal, although I doubt it has anything to do with what's going on). On success, I pass to $.ajax() callback function in success attribute which looks like this:

```
function updateTable(newArray){
    var tableBody = "";

    if (newArray) {

        tableBody =
                "<table>" +
                    "<thead>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                            "<th>Name</th>" +
                            "</tr>" +
                    "</thead>" +
                    "<tbody>";

        for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            tableBody =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + newArray[i].name + "<td>" +
                    "</tr>";
        }

        tableBody = tableBody + "</tbody></table>";
    } 

    $('#divTable').empty();
    $('#divTable').html(tableBody);
}
```

Let's say there is nothing in element  at the beginning. I add some value and get newArray and table is being added, but browser shows only tbody, without header, although I'm checking the source code of website, and there is thead written. Why is that? Does it have connection with rendering table header? I don't think that it's in rendering, because the text that I'm assigning to one `<p>` tag is not changing as well, although it's also included in source code.

I've tried it also with `.append()` after `.empty()` but no change.

Comment: OT: You don't need to call `.empty()` before `.html()`, since `.html()` replaces everything in the DIV.

Comment: Yea, I wasn't calling it, but I got "paranoid" when it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is not appending to `tableBody`, it's replacing it every time. You need to use `+=` instead of `=` in the assignment.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            tableBody +=
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + newArray[i].name + "<td>" +
                    "</tr>";
        }
```

Comment: I cannot believe that I lack concentration that much. Too bad that this question will be of no use to anyone. I guess it's true that you should give someone else to look at your code sometimes.

Comment: Maybe you should also learn to use the debugger. If you put a breakpoint after this statement, you would have seen that all the header stuff is gone.

Comment: Don't feel too bad. I think I've seen dozens of SO questions where someone was doing similar things, like re-initializing a variable inside the loop instead of before the loop.